# How to add items to the other ListBox in VB?

Tags: vb.net, listbox

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1

Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim FindFolder As New FolderBrowserDialog
    FindFolder.ShowDialog()
    TextBox1.Text = FindFolder.SelectedPath
End Sub

Public Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        My.Settings.theSetPath = TextBox1.Text
        My.Settings.isValidPath = True
        My.Settings.Save()
        TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.theSetPath
        Dim folderInfo As New IO.DirectoryInfo(My.Settings.theSetPath)
        Dim txtFilesInFolder() As IO.FileInfo
        Dim cfgFilesInFolder() As IO.FileInfo
        Dim xmlFilesInFolder() As IO.FileInfo
        Dim datFilesInFolder() As IO.FileInfo
        Dim fileInFolder As IO.FileInfo
        txtFilesInFolder = folderInfo.GetFiles("*.txt")
        cfgFilesInFolder = folderInfo.GetFiles("*.cfg")
        xmlFilesInFolder = folderInfo.GetFiles("*.xml")
        datFilesInFolder = folderInfo.GetFiles("*.dat")

        For Each fileInFolder In txtFilesInFolder
            Second.List.Items.Add(fileInFolder.Name)
        Next
        For Each fileInFolder In cfgFilesInFolder
            Second.List.Items.Add(fileInFolder.Name)
        Next
        For Each fileInFolder In xmlFilesInFolder
            Second.List.Items.Add(fileInFolder.Name)
        Next
        For Each fileInFolder In datFilesInFolder
            Second.List.Items.Add(fileInFolder.Name)
        Next
        MsgBox("Testing")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("That is not a valid directory.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
        My.Settings.isValidPath = False
        My.Settings.Save()
    End Try

    Second.Show()

End Sub

Public Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim path As String
    path = TextBox1.Text
End Sub

Public Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

End Class
```

I want the program to get filenames from text files in the specified folder, and then list them on a listBox. But the ListBox is on another GUI.

When I press the button, it's suppose to open up another GUI, and output the filenames to listBox on the second GUI.

I get "That is not a valid directory." For some reason, even though it is valid.

And it doesn't show anything on the other ListBox. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: As long as it's returning the error nothing will be added to the lists.  Copy and paste the value in the textbox1 here.  Perhaps there's something there you're missing.

Comment: Also your catch block should display ex.Message so you know exactly why the exception was thrown.  It might even lead you to the answer.

Comment: The Textbox1's text is the path that the user selects.

Comment: Okay, So I deleted the "Second." from the `Second.List.Items.Add(fileInFolder.Name)`, and now I don't get the "Invalid directory" error, and the info shows up on the first-GUI listboxm but not the second. How else will I get it to show up on the second one?

Comment: Okay, I just added this code to the second forms loading method: `List.Items.Add(Form1.List)` But, I get: `Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.` I'm trying pretty much everything.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, probably, in trying to access the second form directly. To access it from the first form declare a new second form, 'Dim Sec as New Second'. Now you can access all the controls in the second form, from the first. Then use 'Sec.Show()' to show the form.

Also what is the datasource of the listbox in the second form?

Comment: The Datasource is set to none.